# Facebook WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder on Android 2.2

Tags: android, facebook, request

I want do display Facebook WebDialog as a invitation to use the application. I'm using `WebDialog.RequestDialogBuilder()` for creating the `WebDialog`. It works fine on Android versions 2.3.3 and above, but on Android 2.2 the Dialog window appears for just a moment then disappears. `OnCompleteListener` provides `FacebookException` with no message.
Here is my code:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();

params.putString("message", message);
params.putString("to", friendFBId);

RequestsDialogBuilder rdb = new RequestsDialogBuilder(ctx, FBSession, params);

rdb.setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

    @Override
    public void onComplete(Bundle values, FacebookException error) {

        if (error != null){
            if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException){
                //Toast.makeText(ctx,"Request cancelled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
            }
            Log.e("MB", "FB Error: "+error.toString()+" "+error.getMessage());
        }
        else{
            final String requestId = values.getString("request");
            if (requestId != null) {
                Toast.makeText(ctx,"Request sent" +requestId,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } 
            else {
                Toast.makeText(ctx,"Request cancelled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
});

WebDialog requestDialog = rdb.build();
requestDialog.show();
```

My question is: why doesn't this work on Android 2.2?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What exactly is your question?

Comment: Hello! My question is why it doesn't work on Android 2.2